# Conflict when trying to generate two separate numbers

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have the following script, which is meant to generate 2 different numbers

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1() {
    var min = 2, max = 7;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;   
    return random;

}

 var GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1 = GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1(); 
$('.GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1').html(GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1);



 function GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2() {
    var min = 2, max = 7;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;   
  return (random !== GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1) ? random: GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2();

}

 var GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2 = GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2(); 
$('.GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2').html(GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2);

</script>


NUMBER 1:  <span class = "GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1"></span> 

NUMBER 2: <span class = "GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2"></span>
```

This usually works fine but occasionally the page will load and no numbers will appear. I'm guessing this is when `GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2`  happens to generate the same number as `GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1`.  I thought that 
  `return (random !== GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1) ? random: GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2();` accounted for this, but perhaps instead of generating another unique number when there's redundancy, it generates no number at all.  Is this the case? If so, how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is this suppose to do: `var GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1 = GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1();`?

Comment: It sets the variable `GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1` as the output of the function `GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1()` so that I can use it to replace any element with class `.GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1`

Comment: Where are this javascript written inside head?separate js file? or inside body tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRand(){
  var array=[2,3,4,5,6,7]
  var newArray=[];
  for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    var ran=~~(array.length*Math.random());
    newArray[i]=array.splice(ran,1)[0]
  }
  return newArray
}
var ranArray=getRand();
var ran1=ranArray[0];
var ran2=ranArray[1];
console.log(ran1,ran2)
```

getRand() is a function to give you an array of distinct numbers.Since you only need two,it only loop two times,and give you an array,which you can make use of it.

Back to your code,from what I see,Gno2 should keep running until it got another number,I don't know why.It's the time you try to debug.

First I will try to change the `max=2` to `max=3`,if the code may not work for some number,then you can quickly realize and found out the problem is in these two functions.

Then try to log,`console.log(Gno1,Gno2)`,see what exactly the numbers are,also help you to know where is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll use your suggestions to keep playing with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of code can help you

```
var rand1,rand2;
var min = 3; 
var max = 6; 
do {
    rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}while(rand1 === rand2);

$('.GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1').html(rand1);
$('.GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2').html(rand2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice; I'm more so hoping to find a fix to my existing code because it ties in to other parts of my code, but this is much appreciated.